# What kind of inversion is this? "Out come the pocket calculators"

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

Please help me understand the grammar of this sentence:

> When the girls get their bills, out come the pocket calculators.

What connotations does this inversion add? Can "out come" here be analyzed as a phrasal verb? If so, what other phrasal verbs can be inverted this way so that the preposition precedes the verb?

Comment: Are you asking for the difference in connotation between this and "When the girls get their bills, the pocket calculators come out"?

Comment: And yes, I'm asking about this difference.

Comment: In that case, I can't think of a difference. Seems like a choice dictated by style rather than meaning. Verb-first reads a bit more easily.

Comment: I think there's a slight difference in nuance -- the quoted version emphasizes "out come" by putting it first. You envision lots of simultaneous reaching for purses.

Comment: The wording reminds me of the classic chant that accompanies assisted respiration after a instance of near drowning, in fictional comedic works like cartoons and beach movies: "Out goes the bad air; in comes the good air!"

Comment: @Barmar Yes I see what you mean. There's a more dramatic feel to it.

Comment: @Rupe Yeah, I kind of think of it like "they _whip out_ their calculators."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *When the girls get their bills,* ***out come the pocket calculators.***

The main clause of your example has undergone **subject-dependent inversion**:

1. *[the pocket calculators]* ***come*** *[out]* -- (non-inverted)
2. *[out]* ***come*** *[the pocket calculators]* -- (subject-dependent inversion)

In version #1, the subject ("the pocket calculators") is located in its typical slot--before the verb. But in version #2, the subject has switched its location with that of the dependent "out".

There are reasons related to **information packaging** why a writer or speaker might prefer the inverted versions for certain contexts. Some of these reasons are: 1) newer info is often moved to the end of a clause, 2) info that is to be emphasized is often moved to the end of a clause for a stronger effect on the reader. Both of those reasons seem applicable to your example.

Notice how your original sentence reads better (imo) than this more basically structured version:

- *The pocket calculators come out when the girls get their bills.*

In your original version, "the pocket calculators"--by being placed at the end of the sentence--get emphasized to the reader. It was the pocket calculators that the writer wanted to be the main, and unexpected, point of the sentence.